# How to get the terrain height at mouse position when in 2D map?

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm using Cesium in 2D mode.
This is the code I'm using to take the terrain height at mouse position:

```
cartographic = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic( position );
var longitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude).toFixed(10);
var latitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude).toFixed(10);          

mapPointerLatitude = latitudeString.slice(-15);
mapPointerLongitude = longitudeString.slice(-15);
var tempHeight = cartographic.height;
if( tempHeight < 0 ) tempHeight = 0; 
mapPointerHeight = tempHeight.toFixed(2);
```

Where `position` came from a `Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE` event:

```
if ( mapStyle === '2D' ) {
    var position = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(movement.endPosition, scene.globe.ellipsoid);
    if (position) {
        return position;
    } 
}

if ( mapStyle === '3D' ) {
    var ray = viewer.camera.getPickRay(movement.endPosition);
    var position = viewer.scene.globe.pick(ray, viewer.scene);
    if (Cesium.defined(position)) {
        return position;
    } 
}
```

When the map is in 3D mode (`Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D`) I have the height value in `tempHeight` but when the map is in `Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D` this value is always zero. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Don't know if this is the best way but I get it to work putting my code inside this:

```
cartographic = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic( position );

var positions = [ cartographic ];
var promise = Cesium.sampleTerrain(terrainProvider, 11, positions);
Cesium.when(promise, function( updatedPositions ) {
    // PUT ALL HERE
});
```

Comment: missing "var terrainProvider = Cesium.createWorldTerrain();"

Answer (score 2):

You can actually try Cesium.sampleTerrainMostDetailed to get more precise altitude.

```js
// Query the terrain height of two Cartographic positions
const terrainProvider = Cesium.createWorldTerrain();
const positions = [
    Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(86.925145, 27.988257),
    Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(87.0, 28.0)
];
Cesium.sampleTerrainMostDetailed(terrainProvider, positions).then((updatedPositions) => {
    // positions[0].height and positions[1].height have been updated.
    // updatedPositions is just a reference to positions.
})
```

https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/global.html?classFilter=sample#sampleTerrainMostDetailed